# deleting pointer in vector causes error

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, delete-operator

I've been working on a school project and during the testing phase, we keep getting a recurrent error while wanting to delete (de-allocating) anything. Our classes are very basic and do not use pointers as data members. The class that manages the interaction between those two classes uses a vector of pointers to manage them (somewhat easier in this context). We scanned through all the code for double deletion or other similar errors. 
Here is a snipplet of what could cause an error:

```
delete (nodes[i]);
nodes.erase(nodes.begin() + i);
```

nodes being:

```
std::vector<Node*> nodes;
```

I do not want to give the entire code as it is quite large. 
Right now, literally ANY delete operation will not work and crash the program with a: bad_module_info

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is an example:

```
int** matrix = new int*[nodes.size()];

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
    matrix[i] = new int(nodes.size());




for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
{
    ref[i] = nodes[i]->getId();
    cout << ref[i];
}


//Setting up
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++)
{
    int from = edges[i]->getStartNode();
    int to = edges[i]->getEndNode();

    int indexRow = getRefrenceFromID(ref, nodes.size(), from);
    int indexCol = getRefrenceFromID(ref, nodes.size(), to);

    matrix[indexRow][indexCol] = 1;
}

//print the contents of the matrix
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
{
    cout << ref[i] << "|"; //first print the ID of the row
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
        cout << matrix[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for(unsigned int = 0; i < nodes.size();++i)
    delete[] matrix[i];

delete[] matrix;
delete[] ref;
```

Comment: _I do not want to give the entire code as it is quite large._ That's appropriate. Please, reproduce your issue with a [mcve]. Otherwise, it's hard to help you.

Comment: you have created one element by `new int(nodes.size());`, use `new int[nodes.size()];`

Comment: This did work! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `matrix[i] = new int(nodes.size());` is the source of your problem.

```
new int(x); // Create a single int with value x
new int[x]; // Create array of x ints
```

It looks like `matrix[i]` is meant to be an array and not a single int so you should be using `new int[nodes.size()];`

More information on [`new[]` here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/).